# Run Mapreduce job from servlet

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

How do we trigger a map reduce job from a servlet? I have a jsp page that takes in certain parameters from the user. The parameters serve as input to a Map Reduce job. How do I accomplish this task?

As suggested by http://answers.mapr.com/questions/2506/submit-mapreduce-job-remotely

I tried setting the below 2 properties,

```
conf.set(fs.default.name, <the ip/port>) 
conf.set(mapred.job.tracker, <the ip/port>)
```

Unfortunately, it threw the following exception, which I was not able to solve

java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.

Comment: So you are using CDH, HDP, MapR? Give more information about the Hadoop version (obviously you are using YARN), your distribution etc.

Comment: @Thomas, I am using CDH4 hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1

Comment: So what is the value of your propery "mapreduce.framework.name", it should be "yarn".

Comment: @Thomas mapreduce.framework.name is yarn